# laravel get all places for all events where place

Tags: php, laravel-4, orm

I'm finally learning the Laravel ORM, and quite frankly, it's making me depressed as I'm working against a tight deadline.

I'm trying the simplest thing, easily to achieve in SQL in a few seconds, and after half an hour with the ORM, I just can't get it to work.

1 event has 1 place. In EventModel:

```
public function place(){ 
    $this->hasOne('zwoop\models\place\PlaceModel', 'place_id'); 
}
```

1 place can belong to many events. In PlaceModel:

```
public function events(){ 
    $this->belongsToMany('zwoop\models\event\EventModel'); 
}
```

Now in the EventModel, what is the structure to get all events where place is within certain bounds?  (eg. `where place.lat > input_lat and lng > input_lng` (simplified).
I would give example code, but I can't figure it out at all.

This is just the beginning of a query that is really long, I really wonder if the ORM will be the most efficient solution in the end...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) section of the Laravel Docs?

```
EventModel::whereHas('place', function($q) {
    $q->where('lat', '>', input_lat)
        ->where('lng', '>', input_lng);
})->get();
```

Comment: I tried many things, there is always some nonsensical error that pops up. This time it is: `"Call to a member function getRelationCountQuery() on a non-object"`I'm sure it's my fault but I'm under a lot of pressure.

Comment: Never mind it, thanks for your help. Upvoted your answer, and I will go with the query builder for now. I'm just a bit disappointed, thought it would be more intuitive, but it feels harder for me to write and understand than native sql.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. let me explain here a little bit. There are quite several ways to do it. But the most efficient way should be the following:

1. Get all places within certain bounds using 

   `$places = Place::where('lat', '>', input_lat)->where('lng', '>', input_lng)->get();
   $places = $places->lists('id');`
2. Get all events ids using

   `Events::whereIn('place_id', $places)->get();`

It is done!

Of course you can combine the two and make it one query. Personally I do not like mix queries thought it should give you a little boost in performance in your case.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this will bring me into trouble later on in the query. I decided to go with the query builder and define scopes to clean it up. It works well like this. Thanks for your help.